# Single file in custom content element with DCE

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I installed DCE for custom content elements.

I would like a first div tag set conditionally including the filename. This should do it, but it doesn't - why?

```
  <f:if condition="{f:count(subject: {dce:fal(field:'bgImage', contentObject:contentObject)})}==1">
      <f:then>

        <f:for each="{dce:fal(field:'image', contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference" iteration="iterator">
            <f:if condition="{iterator.isFirst}">
                <div class="element slide vertical-center picture{f:if(condition: '{field.isWhite} == 1', then: ' white')}" img-fill="{f:uri.image(src:'{fileReference.uid}',treatIdAsReference:'1')}" selectable>
            </f:if>
        </f:for>

    </f:then>
    <f:else>

        <div class="element slide vertical-center{f:if(condition: '{field.isWhite} == 1', then: ' white')}" selectable>

    </f:else>  
  </f:if>
```

What I need:

I defined a FAL property in DCE and if a file is set, the 'div' should be

```
<div class="element slide vertical-center picture" img-fill="FILEPATH" selectable>
```

if not it should be

```
<div class="element slide vertical-center" selectable>
```

I did not find a netter solution than this structure:

```
<f:for each="{dce:fal(field:'image', contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference" iteration="iterator">
    <f:if condition="{iterator.isFirst}">
        <!-- render image by fileReference -->
    </f:if>
</f:for>
```

I already found the inline notation

```
{f:if(condition:'{filepath} != EMTPY',then:' picture')}
```

But how do I check for EMPTY in fluid?

```
{f:if(condition:'{filepath}',then:' picture')}
```

When I correctly understood Urs in the comments.

What do I miss?

Comment: Of course there is a way to do it. Have you heard about magic function f:debug and its powers to show you what variables do you have accessible in your object except for uid, when your installation is in debug mode?

Comment: Of course, as I said - I found the filereference-object. And well yes, there are the desired properties, but how to get them in that environment? Inside 'f:for {... build whole view with filereference ...}' ? No, what if no image uploaded? First 'f:for {... variable = filereference of first file ...}' then use variable? No, f:alias only for strings and inside f:alias environment. So, what would you do?

Comment: A few hints: AFAIK, `{f:if(condition:'{filepath',then:' picture')}` already means "if not empty". If you want to access the first item of an array, `{files.0}` is often sufficient. And last not least: DCE is a cool solution, but if you're not happy with it also take a look at ext:mask (it's what I use).

Comment: Also, instead of `<f:image src="{fileReference.uid}" alt="" treatIdAsReference="1" />` try `<f:image image="{fileReference}" />` (note the "image" property instead of src. Not sure if leaving out the `.uid` is correct for DCE though.

Comment: You don't HAVE to use inline syntax just to write into a html tag. It's to nest fluid VHs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a "solution" on my own:

```
  <f:for each="{dce:fal(field:'bgImage', contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference" iteration="iterator">

    <f:if condition="{iterator.isFirst}">

      <div class="element slide vertical-center picture{f:if(condition: '{field.isWhite} == 1', then: ' white')}" img-fill-src="/fileadmin{fileReference.originalFile.identifier}">

    </f:if>

  </f:for>

  <f:if condition="<f:count>{dce:fal(field:'bgImage', contentObject:contentObject)}</f:count> < 1">

    <div class="element slide vertical-center{f:if(condition: '{field.isWhite} == 1', then: ' white')}">

  </f:if>
```

What a mess. Compare to a PHP approach:

```
<? if (count($image_references) == 1): ?>

  <div class="element slide vertical-center picture" img-fill-src="/fileadmin<? echo $file_references[0].originalFile.identifier; ?>">

<? else: ?>

  <div class="element slide vertical-center">

<? endif; ?>

</div>
```

And with this Fluid stuff you generate extreme overhead because after all you need a parser that parses the Fluid stuff. This parser is again written in PHP and muss be executed throughout to the frontend. That means everything has to be cached. But caching again is not good. The code is more easy. If you learn fluid you can't apply it somewhere else unlike PHP.

**What a bad idea this "Fluid"-System is!**

Comment: this is not the right place for a discussion about the fluid templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

So, you might try something like this (I'm guessing):

```
<div class="..." img-fill="<f:if condition="{dce:fal(field:'image', contentObject:contentObject)}">
      <f:image image="{dce:fal(field:'image', contentObject:contentObject).0}" />
  </f:if>
  </f:for>">
 ... further content ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that does not work and couldn't: '{dce:fal(field:'image', contentObject:contentObject)}' ist the array of fileReferences. Ergo: 'files' as you used it here will not be an array of fileReferences anymore, but an fileReference itself.

Comment: Ah yeah, right, sorry! I misread the code. I've edited the answer; that's what I meant; while I'm not sure if the syntax around the .0 is correct. But `dce:fal....` sees to be an array, so just access the first item.

Comment: Unfortunately not: `<f:debug>{dce:fal(field:'bgImage', contentObject:contentObject).0}</f:debug>` will return a string (which obviously means the fluid-parser cannot resolve the expression). `<f:debug>{dce:fal(field:'bgImage', contentObject:contentObject)}</f:debug>` will still return the fileReference array.

Answer (score 0):

try to something like this, it's work for me.

```
  <f:for each="{dce:fal(field:'fal', contentObject:contentObject)}" as="fileReference" iteration="iterator">
    <div class="element slide vertical-center {f:if(condition:'{fileReference.uid}',then:' picture')}">
            <f:image src="{fileReference.uid}" alt="" treatIdAsReference="1" />
    </div>
</f:for>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. It would iterate at least once if there were no image set by the user. but thank you. I solved it.